# How to aggregate certain elements in a list of disctionaries

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of dictionaries (state:(score, type)) `list1` and would like to aggregate the states within each disctionary of `list1` based on `list2`.

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = [{'NY':(40, 'EQ'), 'NJ':(30, 'EQ'), 'CT':(10, 'EQ'),'FL':(30, 'FI'), 'IL':(60, 'AI')}, {'NY':(40, 'EQ'), 'NJ':(50, 'EQ'), 'GA':(10, 'RE'), 'CA':(20, 'HA')}] 

list2 = ['NY', 'NJ', 'CT']
```

For the first `list1` element, aggregate `'NY', 'NJ', and 'CT'`. For the second `list1` element, aggregate `'NY' and 'NJ'`.

So that the expected output after aggregation is:

```
list1 =  [{'NY':(80, 'EQ'),'FL':(30, 'FI'), 'IL':(60, 'AI')}, {'NY':(90, 'EQ'), 'GA':(10, 'RE'), 'CA':(20, 'HA')}]
```

Thanks.

Comment: what's holding you back here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
df=pd.DataFrame(list1)
a=df.loc[:, list2].sum(axis=1).reset_index(name='s').drop('index', 1)
df.loc[:, 'NY'] = a['s']
df.drop(['NJ','CT'], axis = 1,inplace=True)
list2=df.apply(lambda x : x.dropna().to_dict(),axis=1).tolist()
print(list2)
```